# Russia, how to politely ask a taxi driver for seatbelts?

Tags: safety, russia, taxis

In Russia, what is a polite way to ask a taxi driver for a seatbelt. Most of them don't wear seatbelts and don't expect their passengers too. Is it acceptable to refuse to pay/ride the taxi for no seatbelts without a cancellation fee?

To clarify, I want to wear a seatbelt, but sometimes they are refused to be provided.

Comment: Do you want the taxi driver to wear a seatbelt or just yourself?

Comment: @Ian Just myself for safety, sometimes they can refuse to provide them

Comment: How can a taxi driver refuse to provide seat belts? Either they are installed or not, right?

Comment: @Ian covered by a cloth which he says you can't take off

Comment: Taxi drivers are, at least in the Netherlands, allowed to drive without seatbelts, for safety reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in a taxi and there's no seatbelts, you're definitely in a **wrong kind of taxi**. Better not board anything like that.

This is after we exclude small remote towns where it's still not uncommon. As a rule you can expect taxi car to be in reasonable condition, and this includes seat belts for all passengers.

Sometimes for the seats in a back, seat belts may not be easily accessible. You will have to dig them out of the seat, or just **ride in the front seat**. It's a preferred option in Russia anyway.

Obviously if you're unhappy about your taxi and you hailed it via app or phone, you can use the same app/phone to **cancel your ride and complain**.